# In protractor, I want the code to handle based on if OTP triggers and if not, I can login to the home page or any page and cont do the work

Tags: protractor

I am new to coding and as well as to protractor.

In protractor, I want the code to handle based on if OTP triggers go and retrieve OTP and if not, login to the home page or any page and continue to do the actions in the home page. I was trying to do an if else check with 
I tried as like below

```
browser.getcurrentUrl().toEqual().then function()
{
  statements;
},
```

I don't think it works. Can someone help?

Comment: SO is a terrible tutorial site. Your best bet is to figure out the basics and come back with a specific question for problems you run into. "I don't think it works" is not a question. _How_ does it not work? What are you trying to do, what have your tried as a [mcve] and what results did you get. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

below is my code snippet.

Basically i was trying to check the url, if it contains specific texts in it, I dont want anything to perform further execution want to exit out of execution. If the url doesnt contain anything specified I want to proceed with further execution.

The if condition is working fine. but not the else part.

```
var HomePages = require('../Pages/HomePage.js');

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
describe(‘Check_url function’, function() {
browser.wait(EC.urlContains(’some url’),2000).then(result => {
      if (result) {
        console.log('Sorry!!!!!!!, Encountered PassCode Authentication Process. 
          Execution cant be proceed further');
        } else {
          HomePages.profile();
          browser.driver.sleep(300);
        }
      });
});

//////////////////////////
HomePages.js - 

'use strict';
module.exports = {

Homepage: {
 usrname: element(by.className('profile-name')),
 usricon: element(by.css('[title="profile"]')),
 Cli_id: element(by.css('[title=“Client ID"]'))

},

profile: function() {
    this.click_Profile();

 },

  click_Profile: function() {

      var angular3 = this.Homepage;
      angular3.usricon.click();   


  },
```